# rake: command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rake

I'm trying to install rails on Ubuntu 9.10.

```
gem list --local

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (2.3.4, 2.3.2)
actionpack (2.3.4, 2.3.2)
activerecord (2.3.4, 2.3.2)
activeresource (2.3.4, 2.3.2)
activesupport (2.3.4, 2.3.2)
rack (1.0.1)
rails (2.3.4, 2.3.2)
rake (0.8.7)
sqlite3-ruby (1.2.5)

rake
The program 'rake' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install rake
rake: command not found
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: @MR: But it *is* listed as an installed gem.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need to add */var/lib/gems/1.8/bin* to your *PATH*. Try this command:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin
```

After that *rake* should work.

You can add this line to your ~/.bashrc so that you don't have to type in this command each time.

Comment: THANKYOUTHANKYOUTHANKYOU I have been having this problem for MONTHS and stumbled over this Q on accident...

Comment: Note: use "gem env" to get your gem path

Comment: I ran this, and get "not a git repo" Where should I run it from?

Answer (score 9):

Gem is complaining about the rake **program** (i.e. executable), not the rake **gem** (you have the latter already installed).

That means that you have to add rake exec to the PATH. Possible rake bin location is `/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/rake`. Add it to your PATH then:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin
```

You can also install Rake from the Ubuntu repository (as suggested in the gem output):

```
sudo apt-get install rake
```

Answer (score 1):

They are correct, you need to have rake in your path.  However if you want to make sure it's just there, instead of exporting it from .bashrc, make a symbolic link:

`sudo ln -s /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/rake /usr/bin/rake`

If you do that, you should always be able to use it.

Comment: That should happen, this is nearly the same as copying the file the directory.  Check the path that is set when using root.  Is this on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

The solution, at least for me, is making the symbolic link.

This is the kind of issue I have to remember. Every time I set a new Ubuntu machine I run into this little problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem on Centos 5.5 and self compiled ruby and rails. (Need it for redmine) When i tried to install passenger using passenger-install-apache2-module, I did an strace and round out, that passenger looks for rake in the **ruby/bin** directory and not the **gems/bin** directory, where rake was installed. So a

```
ln -s /usr/local/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin/rake /usr/local/ruby1.8.7/bin
```

solved it for me. (/usr/local/ruby1.8.7 is where i installed ruby...)